# Javascript used in URL

Tags: javascript, xss

Looking through analytics, I saw that someone visited my cart page and added the following to the URL:

```
cart?wvstest=javascript:domxssExecutionSink(1,%2522%253Cbr%253E()locxss%2522)
```

What would this do, and should I be considered of any security issues?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com would be better place to ask this.

Answer (score 8):

It's an attempt at injecting JavaScript by penetration tool [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/support/vulnerability-checks/).  The specfic attack is [DOM based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) (as shown by the function named `domxssExecutionSink`).  If you were to echo the query parameter `wvstest` directly to the page, their JavaScript would have been executed.

[Read more about XSS atacks (and how to mitigate them) at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

Comment: What's the best way to make sure the attack hasn't gotten through?

Comment: @JordanBundy that's very implementation-specific, read the last link to learn more.  Remember, always sanitize user input.

Comment: @JordanBundy visit the page but with some obvious JavaScript as the parameter such as `cart?wvstest=javascript:alert(123)` - see if this alert box appears in the response directly or on any other page (e.g. whatever page processes this input and displays it).

Answer (score 1):

It will pass the data to your server.

What happens next depends on your server side code.

If you were to read `wvstest` as a query string and then inject it (without proper sanitisation) into an HTML document, you would have [an XSS security hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: How should I double check to make sure that isn't happening?